# Uploading file via html form. In PHP, $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, html, file, web, upload

So I have this code:

```
<form name="form" action="./" method="post">
<input type="file" name="newfile" id="newfile" />
</form>
```

When I run this php script on the action page, nothing happens

```
echo "$_FILES['newfile']['name'];
print_r($_FILES);
```

It is like the `$_FILES` variable is empty. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on your form.

[Example 1 from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify `<form … enctype="multipart/form-data">` then the data will be encoded in a way that doesn't support files.

Add the attribute with that value.

From [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype):

> **enctype = content-type [CI]**
>
> This attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of method is "post"). The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the INPUT element, type="file".

From [the PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$_FILES['newfile']['name'];
```

That's a syntax error. Should be

```
echo $_FILES['newfile']['name'];
```

or

```
echo "{$_FILES['newfile']['name']}";
```